# I/O port-mapped or memory-mapped device?

Tags: linux-kernel

**Introduction:**

I am trying to "say" something to my virtual device ( I mean virtualbox). So first, I have to know I/O port or Memory address region.

So, let look at my lspci output:

```
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64 (63750ns min)
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at d010 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
    Kernel modules: e1000
```

**Problem**

So there are two region and I don't understand why there are two regions. I don't know 
if device is memory-mapped or port-mapped? I don't understand how can I write bytes to my device. What address I should choose?

Comment: Answering these questions would not help you using the device. You have to know the registers of the 82540 chip, and how they work.

Comment: So, I should study http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/pci-pci-x-family-gbe-controllers-software-dev-manual.pdf, should I?

Comment: Yes, and it answers your questions.